# How to find objects with circle hole inside

Tags: matlab

Hello in the following picture i need to find objects that have circle hole inside of it.I tried to use euler number but it allowed me to find all holes not only circles.
[image: Shapes]

Comment: [`imfindcircles`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html). Please also add your attempt in the question

Comment: I don't have any specific code. Just can't find any way that would work

Comment: Your exact words are: *"I tried to use euler number but it allowed me to find all holes not only circles. "* Please show that try.

Comment: If the color of the holes are same, you can  extract them first and then apply `imfindcircles`, this will also eliminate the bottom right circle from the result

Comment: Also, after proper binarization, the Euler number will give you the right result. If you show how you computed it, we might be able to point out what you did wrong.